# Difference between a = Loss and a = Loss()

Tags: python, function, pytorch

I'm curious what the difference between the following lines of code are:

```
a = torch.nn.BCELoss
```

and

```
b = torch.nn.BCELoss()
```

I find it very interesting, that both ways work for PyTorch's BCE Loss. However, if I try to do this with a custom function, I can not do this:

```
b2 = my_func()
```

This throws an error about the missing arguments. Only

```
a2 = my_func
```

works. My function is defined as follows:

```
def my_func(m,n):
    return m+n
```

Also, why does

```
b(x,y)
```

work perfectly fine but

```
a(x,y)
```

Throw a error? (RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous).

Comment: `BCELoss` is the class, `BCELoss()` creates an instance object of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are first-class objects (no pun intended) in Python; you can treat them as values like any other value. `torch.nn.BCELoss` is just an expression that evaluates to a class reference. Classes are callable, so `torch.nn.BCELoss()` is a *call* to that class.

You could also have written

```
x = torch.nn.BCELoss
b = x()
```

and it would work the same. `x` and `torch.nn.BCELoss` both evaluate to the same `class` object.

Similarly,

```
a2 = my_func
```

only makes `a2` another name for the function referred to by `my_func`. (Functions are also first-class objects.)

`b(x,y)` is the same as `torch.nn.BCELoss()(x,y)`, while `a(x,y)` is the same as `torch.nn.BCELoss(x,y)`. The former calls an *instance* of the class; the latter the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Python has 'first-class functions', which means that a function isn't really *syntactically special* like it is in Java. Instead, a function is essentially just an object that has the `__call__()` method defined. When you write a function with `def`, python will figure this part out manually.

When you do

```
def my_func(m,n):
    return m+n
```

python creates an object named `my_func` of type `function`. When called, it will execute the interior of the function.

You can either call the function, which will execute it and return the requisite value (`m + n`):

```
aa = my_func(1, 2)
# aa is now 3, because the function returned 1 + 2
```

or you can assign the function to another variable *without calling it*.

```
bb = my_func
# the names `my_func` and `bb` now refer to the same thing, which is a function

cc = bb(3, 4)
# cc is now 7, because the function returned 3 + 4
```

Obviously you can't now call `cc()`, because `cc` is an integer, and calling an integer doesn't make sense. This is the case for *most* functions - the thing that they return when you call them is usually not itself callable.